# Array of string in a struct pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, malloc

I have a following struct:

```
strcut records
{
    char **lines;
    int count;
}
```

There is a function `get_pwent()` which the concerning code is like this:

```
struct records *passwd = malloc(sizeof(strcut records));
passwd->lines = malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_STR_SIZE);
```

With a few malloc error checking (`passwd` is not null, `passwd->lines` is not null) it's passed down to my `parse_file()`:

```
parse_file(struct records *record, FILE * in)
{
    int i = 0;

    ... // a while loop
    fgets((*record).lines[i], MAX_STR_SIZE, in); // <-- Segment fault here
    i++;
    ... // end while
}
```

The file is /etc/passwd and I want to read in the first line of this file and store that into the struct records lines[i] position.

I also tried this:

```
fgets(record->lines[i], ...) //which also gets a seg fault.
```

in GDB, under `parse_file()` scope:

```
(gdb) p record
$1 = {struct records *} 0x602250
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you make sure `record` is not NULL, `record->lines` is not NULL, and `record->lines[i]` is a string allocated with `MAX_STR_SIZE`?

Comment: @crashmstr I made sure that `passwd` (`record` in `parse_file` scope) is not `NULL`, and so does its `lines`.

Comment: I suspect allocating actual memory for the target of that `fgets` will considerably increase chances for success. Right now you allocate the array of *pointers*, but the value of each pointer is  indeterminate. You allocate no space for the actual string read. With that, you invoke *undefined behavior*, and (fortunately) crash in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for each line before you can copy data to it:

```
  record->line[i] = malloc(MAX_STR_SIZE+1);    // allocate memory first.
  fgets((*record).lines[i], MAX_STR_SIZE, in); // <-- Segment fault here
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Initially I thought there was no need to allocate `record->line[i]` because it was an array of pointers to `char *` but I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an allocation step; for each `passwd->lines[i]`, you need to do another allocation:

```
// Allocate space for array of pointers
passwd->lines = malloc( sizeof *passwd->lines * max_number_of_strings );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < max_number_of_strings; i++ )
{
  // Allocate space for each string
  passwd->lines[i] = malloc( sizeof *passwd->lines[i] * max_string_length );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will make a note for myself of that.